# jBoss EAR-EJB jndi java:global working, java:app NameNotFoundException

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, jndi, ear

We have a EAR containing some jars, an EJB module and a WAR module. We want to obtain a class with JNDI InitialContext.lookup from, and to the same EJB module.

In the jBoss console we can see the java:global with the application, the module and all the classes inside the module. If we do the lookup like that it works.
There is also an applications section that includes our EAR with the module and all the classes inside.

Now that our EAR can have different executions, and therefore different binary names, we wanted to use java:app to skip the hardcoded AppName. To our surprise, even if the java:app exists in the jBoss console JNDI listing, it throws all the time a NameNotFoundException. We also tried with java:comp, java:module, java:app/env/... (even if they are not shown in the jBoss console) but nothing except the portable names work.

Does anyone know why this could be happening?

```
private static final String MY_TIMER_SINGLETON = "java:global/myear-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/mymoduleejb/MyTimerSingleton";

//private static final String MY_TIMER_SINGLETON = "java:app/mymoduleejb/MyTimerSingleton";

InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
MyTimerSingleton t = (MyTimerSingleton) ic
        .lookup(MY_TIMER_SINGLETON);
```

JBoss console Profile->Container->Naming:

```
java:jboss
 -...

java:global
 -myear-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  -mymoduleejb
   -MyTimerSingleton
   -...

applications
 -myear-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  -java:app
   -mymoduleear
    -MyTimerSingleton
    -...
```

EDIT 1: Additional information.

jBoss is running using standalone-ha.xml configuration.

I am trying to get the Singleton through JDNI because @EJB does not work in org.jboss.msc.service.Service classes.

If I make MyTimerSingleton implement a @Remote or @Local interface, the JNDI of the JBoss console becomes empty.

In any case all the .../env/ of the JNDI list are empty

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming **MyTimerSingleton** is an EJB, if it is then you don't need JNDI, you can use the **@EJB** annotation, even for calling the EJB from the Web Module inside the ear.

```
...
@Stateless
public class OtherEJB {
@EJB
MyTimerSingleton myTimerSingleton;
...
```

If you wan't to achieve a loosely coupled solution using JNDI calls, try using the **mappedName** property inside the **@Stateless** or **@Singleton** annotation in the **EJB MyTimerSingleton**:

```
...
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
@Singleton(mappedName = "MyTimerSingleton")
public class MyTimerSingleton implements MyTimerSingletonDef {
...
```

You need to write/generate the **EJB @Local or @Remote interface** too.

```
...    
@Remote
public interface MyTimerSingletonDef {
...
```

Java-EE providers implementation of **mappedNames** support may be different, generally the JNDI NAME of the EJB module is something like this: **java:module/ejb-mappedName-property!canonical-ejb-interface-name** or **java:module/ejb-mappedName-property#canonical-ejb-interface-name**, so you'll get something like this:

```
java:module/MyTimerSingleton!example.package.MyTimerSingletonDef
```

or this

```
java:module/MyTimerSingleton#example.package.MyTimerSingletonDef
```

According to [this blog](http://blog.akquinet.de/2014/09/26/jboss-eap-wildfly-three-ways-to-invoke-remote-ejbs/), and the [JBoss documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Remote+EJB+invocations+via+JNDI+-+EJB+client+API+or+remote-naming+project) in the case of JBoss and WildFly

> Since Java EE 6 the JNDI name syntax of an EJB
>   component has the following structure:

```
[/<application-name>]/<module-name>/<bean-name>[!<full-qualified-interface-name>]
```

> By default, the application name is the filename of the enterprise
>   archive. Therefore, it is recommended to configure the application
>   name in the application.xml deployment descriptor of the enterprise
>   archive, as shown below.

```
<application xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee  http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/application_7.xsd"
        version="7">
    <application-name>myapp</application-name>
    ...
</application>
```

> It is also recommended to configure the module name of the ejb module.
>   Otherwise, the module name is by default the filename of the ejb
>   archive. The module name can be configured with the ejb-jar.xml
>   deployment descriptor.

```
<ejb-jar xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_2.xsd"
    version="3.2">
    <module-name>remote</module-name>
</ejb-jar>
```

> An EJB component will be registered, according to the spec, within the
>   namespaces java:global, java:app, and java:module.

So you'll get something like this in the server console:

```
java:global/myapp/remote/MyTimerSingleton!example.package.MyTimerSingletonDef
java:app/myapp/remote/MyTimerSingleton!example.package.MyTimerSingletonDef
java:module/myapp/MyTimerSingleton!example.package.MyTimerSingletonDef
```

So, the solution may be configuring the application(in application.xml) and the ejb-module(ejb-jar.xml) names to always get the same portable JNDI name.

Comment: Actually, I forgot to say that I call the lookup from a org.jboss.msc.service.Service, so I can't do @EJB to inject the class (it injects null). I tryed the other solutions but I am getting the same NameNotFoundException (with both Remote and Local). No new entries are added to the jBoss console Names section.

Comment: Have you tried using the java-ee(ejb-jar.xml) or the jboss(jboss.xml) ejb deployment descriptors???

Comment: I created a ejb-jar.xml file but nothing changes. I detected a problem when using your second solution in your answer. At the moment I make the class MyTimerSingleton implement the interfaces Local and Remote, the JNDI names listing of the jBoss console is empty in my module. If I don't put the implements statement, it contains the names as described in the question. I am going to add some extra information in the question to clarify it

Comment: @XaviGG, I extended my answer to clarify how the jndi works on JBoss since JavaEE 6.

Comment: I tried with the application.xml, if I just put the lines you told me it does not deploy, I have to add the modules and lib-directory too. I do not know why but one of the modules is correctly added with all its JNDI but the other one is empty (the jar names are correct and are well inside the ear). I found out a work-around by using the non-portable EJB(name = "java:jboss/exported/MyTimerSingleton", beanInterface = MyTimerSingleton.class) and then I access it with java:jboss/exported/MyTimerSingleton

Comment: I am still interested in having application.xml working if you have an idea of why the ejb module is empty inside. Thanks a lot @Rafael-Guillen